# $f(x)=u(x)+iv(x)$ is measurable iff $A_{r,z}=\{x:|f(x)-z|<r \}, r\in \mathbb R , z \in \mathbb C$

Tags: calculus, analysis, measure-theory

$f(x)=u(x)+iv(x)$ is said to be measurable when $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are meausurable Prove that $f(x)$ is measurable iff when $A_{r,z}=\{x:|f(x)-z|<r \}, r \in \mathbb R , z \in \mathbb C$ is measurable, || is the module of a complex number...

I have done this, at least I find I have and wanted some input on how someone else would go about doing it. Every opinion,general idea is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "only if" side prove that translations on $\mathbb C$ are measurable and that $||:\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$ is measurable. Then the function $x\mapsto|f(x)-z|$ will be measurable as a composition of measurable functions. Consequently sets like $A_{r,z}$ are measurable as preimages of $(-\infty,r)$.

Conversely observe that $A_{r,z}=f^{-1}(B_{r,z})$ where $B_{r,z}\subseteq\mathbb C$ is the open ball in $\mathbb C$ with center $z$ and radius $r$. So denoting this collection of open balls with $\mathcal B$ we have $f^{-1}(\mathcal B)\subseteq\mathcal A$ where $\mathcal A$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra on the domain of $f$. Then (story apart) we have $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal B))=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal B))\subseteq\mathcal A$. This means that *every* open set on $\mathbb C$ has a measurable preimage under $f$. Also half-planes like $\{z\in\mathbb C\mid\text{Re}z<r\}$. Based on that it can be shown that $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are measurable.